# Troubles installing mod_ssl on RHEL 5

Tags: mod-ssl

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install mod_ssl
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_ssl available.
Nothing to do
```

This my yum repo list:

```
Loaded plugins: security
repo id                                                               repo name                                                                                      status
rpmforge                                                              RHEL 5Server - RPMforge.net - dag                                                              enabled: 11,089
repolist: 11,089
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is - there's no package called mod_ssl in the repository.

To get Apache working with SSL, the packages you need are httpd and openssl.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that it should'nt be installed that way, but instead using something like:

yum install openssl / something similar.